# ASP.NET Core 2.1 - Error Implementing MemoryCache

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, asp.net-core

I was following the steps given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-2.2#using-imemorycache) to implement a `MemoryCache` in `ASP.NET Core` and when i start the application (`dotnet run` from command prompt), i get the following error.

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Distributed.IDistributedCache' while
>   attempting to activate
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.DistributedSessionStore'.

What is confusing me is that i am using `services.AddMemoryCache()` and **NOT** `services.AddDistributedMemoryCache()`. Full stack trace is available in this [bin](https://pastebin.com/cnCzZ630).
 I have only these packages referenced

> ```
> <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
> <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.1.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
> <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="4.5.0" />
> ```

My `Configure`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
    app.UseSession();
    app.UseCors(
        builder => builder
            .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowCredentials());
    app.UseMvc(
        routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                "default",
                "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
        });
}
```

ConfigureServices

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors();
    services
        .AddMvcCore()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
        .AddJsonFormatters();

    services.AddMemoryCache();

    // Angular files will be served from this directory
    services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration => { configuration.RootPath = "wwwroot"; });
    services.AddSession(
        options =>
        {
            // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        });
}
```

Program.cs

```
  public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
```

Comment: would it be worthwhile downloading the sample [https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/performance/caching/memory/sample] and comparing to your code?

Comment: can you check your *.csproj xml file for refs for any ref to `IDistributedCache` that you may need to clear out if it was previously added

Comment: @JohnB I am getting a `404` on that link.

Comment: Can you please publish Program.cs  and Startup.cs

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat Please see my updated question.

Comment: @JamesPoulose can you comment this line  app.UseSession(); ?

Comment: @JamesPoulose I have updated my answer. Basically session depends on distributed cache

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat Bravo! - that fixed it.  I had to add that to enable session support (`HttpContext.Session`). Looks like that was conflicting with `MemoryCache`. Since `MemoryCache` is working now, i can remove `app.UseSession()`. Please provide these as an answer and i will accept it. Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: @JamesPoulose No its not conflicting its just that use session depends on distributed cache which make sense. But it seems to be that you've added at same time use session and memory cache and confused you. glad that it helps :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be that you try to inject [IDistributedCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-2.2) which is different from memory cache.
Distributed cache will be using external services to store cache while memory cache is going to use servers memory.

As I said something,somewhere is using distributed cache. And that something [is session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

From that page

> The default session provider in ASP.NET Core loads session records from the underlying IDistributedCache

Comment: As i have mentioned in the question, I am not using (at least knowingly) `IDistributedCache` (`services.AddDistributedMemoryCache()`). I am using `services.AddMemoryCache()`.

Comment: @JamesPoulose its not about what you add to services, something somewhere wants to inject distributed cache.

Comment: Removing `app.UseSession()` from `Configure` method was the key - thanks!

Comment: services.AddDistributedMemoryCache() and services.AddMemoryCache() worked for me

Answer (score 13):

Simply adding `services.AddMemoryCache()` after `services.AddControllers()` worked for me.

Comment: This is great as even chatgpt failed to remove error after many hours  which is resolved by just this suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The AddDistributedMemoryCache method adds an implementation of IDistributedCache that uses server memory for storage. It's not a distributed memory cache. The documentation for it says as much.

So, you can safely use it to resolve the error you're seeing without adverse effects. Or just don't use anything that requires an IDistributedCache, such as the UseSession method.